# How to use identity on a column in .dbf?

Tags: c#, .net, odbc, dbf

I am using this code to create a .dbf file and it works fine ( i use OdbcConnection )

```
    string TblInventory = "Create Table Inventory (Id int , Date datetime, CreatedBy char(100))";
    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(TblInventory, odbconn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Insert works well:

```
"Insert Into Inventory (Id, Date , CreatedBy ) Values(2,'2010/05/05','Gigi')";
```

How can i make the Id column autoincrement?

Comment: Switch to SQL Server Express. Isn't .DBF dBASE, and didn't that die about 10 years ago?

Comment: You are correct but it's not up to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using CREATE TABLE INVENTORY (ID autoinc, ....

Answer (score 0):

Use `AUTOINC` of `CREATE TABLE` to enable auto-incrementing.

```
[AUTOINC [NEXTVALUE NextValue [STEP StepValue]]] [DEFAULT eExpression1]
```

Take a look at the following links for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa976850%28VS.71%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa977477%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

```
string TblInventory = "Create Table Inventory (Id i autoinc nextvalue 1 step 1, Date datetime, CreatedBy char(100))";
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(TblInventory, odbconn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```